# Usage of font_size_input_default_unit

Tags: tinymce-6

Can % be used in font_size_input_default_unit?

I have tried font_size_input_default_unit: '%'
but doesn't work

We want users to input % for font sizes.

We have set     font_size_formats: ~'75=75% 100=100% 125=125% 150=150% 200=200%~'
So it is better to use % as font size default.

I have also tried to the font-size in .css but still doesn't work.
If I remove defaults from css, it will still display 16pt.